# Getting a function constant values from it's f(x)

Tags: functions

Hello I'm new to this StackExchange site, in case this is off topic please point me out in the right direction.

It's been about 3 years since I solved a math problem so I need some directions (not asking you to solve the problem, but to tell me where do I start since my brain is starting the engine at the moment).

The problem is, given the quadratic function $$f(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$$,  where $f(-2) = 41$ and $f(5) = 20$, get $A$, $B$, $C$.

I tried starting from the fact that for $x = -2$, $y = 41$, but I'm stuck, I feel I'm missing something, could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Wrong sub-site: you want *MATH.stackexchange.com*...

Comment: Anyhow you don't have enough information to find a unique solution. You have three unknowns $A$, $B$, and $C$, but only two equations $f(-2)=41$ and $f(5)=20$.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 unknowns (A, B, and C), but only two conditions (f(-2)=41, f(5)=20) - so you can't find unique values of all variables.

However, the steps that I'd take in trying to solve this kind of problem would look like so:

1 . Write down the equations with conditions substituted in.

$ 25A + 5B + C = 20 \\
4A - 2B + C = 41 $

2 . Subtract equation 2 from equation 1, to get rid of C.

$21A + 7B = -21$

3 . Write A in terms of B.

$A = -1 -\frac{1}{3}B$

1. If we had a third condition, we could do a similar thing for C, and then use that information to find a unique value of each A, B, and C.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_] := a*x^2 + b*x + c
```

As pointed out by Rahul Narain there is no unique solution; however, you can choose which variable is left and which form is easiest to work with.

```
pairs = Subsets[{a, b, c}, {2}]
```

> {{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}}

```
f[x] /.
 (Solve[{f[-2] == 41, f[5] == 20}, #] & /@
   pairs)
```

> {{c + (-(27/2) + (3*c)/10)*x + 
>          (1/10)*(35 - c)*x^2}, 
>      {45 + (10*b)/3 + b*x + 
>          (1/3)*(-3 - b)*x^2}, 
>      {35 - 10*a - 3*(1 + a)*x + 
>          a*x^2}}

Comment: If you set $A = 0$, then the problem reduces to the much simpler task of finding the line through $(-2,41)$ and $(5,20)$!